# How to use inputs to do calculations with mathfilters in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am using mathfilters in Django, I want to do a multiplication between quantity and unit_price and reflect it in total_price. I already followed the documentation from here mathfilters and when implementing it as it says and filling those 2 inputs with numbers, the result is not reflected anywhere

Maybe I am not implementing it well but when I search I see that there is very little information to use mathfilters

[image: the result of the operation is not reflected]

> presupuestos-forms.html

```
<td>
   {{presupuestosparteform.quantity}}
</td>
<td>
   {{presupuestosparteform.unit_price}}
</td>
<td>
  <li>{{ presupuestosparteform.quantity|mul:presupuestosparteform.unit_price }}</li>
</td>
```

> Presupuestos/views.py

```
def create_Presupuestos(request):
    extra_forms = 0
    ParteFormSet = formset_factory(ParteForm, extra=extra_forms, max_num=20)
    formset = ParteFormSet()
    presupuestosparteform=PresupuestosParteForm(request.POST or None)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        pass

    if presupuestosclientesform.is_valid():
        presupuestosclientesform.save()
        return redirect('presupuestos:index')
    return render(request,'Presupuestos/presupuestos-forms.html',{'presupuestosparteform':presupuestosparteform,'formset':formset})
```

> Parte/views.py

```
def create_Parte(request):
    form=ParteForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('parte:index')
    return render(request,'Parte/parte-form.html',{'form':form})
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier just to do `total_price = quantity * unit_price` in your Python code and add `total_price` to the data you're supplying to the form?

Comment: you mean to put that in the views?

Answer (score 0):

**Pls attach your view file**

You are using the django-mathfilter in the right way. I thing there must be some problem with your values you are providing over there

- check the type of `{presupuestosparteform.quantity}` and `presupuestosparteform.unit_price`
- the value of `presupuestosparteform.unit_price` and `presupuestosparteform.unit_price` must be of int or float type .
- check out the python version must be  `Python 3.5+`

Comment: I just added the view to the question. Well they are both like:
type = "number", otherwise, I have installed the latest version of python. And now that you comment it seems that it is a problem with the views or with the values. Since I was also doing tests with Javascript and it showed me Null ... but I don't know how to make it get the value of the input, store it and show the operation

Comment: and what type of number is it ?int or float check that

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a model @property. This will enable you to make further calculation if needed like deducting discounts etc.
Just add the following property directly to your model:

```
@property
def total_price(self):
    return self.quantity * self.unit_price
```

Comment: yes, in fact I tried but it didn't work, it didn't show the result where it should, look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70149513/how-do-i-make-a-calculation-appear-from-models-in-my-html-template

Comment: Just add `total_price` to list_display for Django admin, to your table or elsewhere. It will show up.